# Accessing Liberty log files from the Bluemix Liberty docker image running locally

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

My goal is to develop an application that will run on WebSphere Liberty hosted in Docker and eventually running on Bluemix.  During development, I have installed Docker on my local Linux PC and then downloaded from IBM the base docker image containing a configured Liberty.  This image is called:

`registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty`

I now start this image in Docker locally in my PC and attach a shell so that I can see what is going on.  I find that there is a Liberty server located at

`/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer`

Now here comes the puzzle.

In Liberty servers I am used to working upon, the messages produced by a server are written into a "logs/messages.log" file relative to the server.  This would mean that I would have expected to find the Liberty message files here:

`/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/messages.log`

However, when I start my server, there is nothing there.

How can I access the logs of my Liberty server obtained from the Bluemix base image (`registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty`) running under Docker natively on my Linux environment on my local PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we examine this IBM Liberty/Bluemix documentation page:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/images/docker_image_ibmliberty/ibmliberty_starter.html

We will find a section that reads:

> Note: All ibmliberty images are configured to write Liberty log files to the directory /logs inside the container. All other files that are written by the Liberty server, are created in the directory /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer. You can access these files by using the shortcut /output.

And this is the key.  The Liberty server log files can be found in `/logs` (that is the directory called `logs` south of the root of the file system).